# Entity Framework proxycreation misery

Tags: c#, entity-framework

ive seen quite a few solutions on problems which are always similar to mine. But none of them satisfied my needs specifically.

I have the following setup:

```
public class User
{
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<PhoneBook> Phonebooks { get; set; }
}

public class PhoneBook
{
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Int32 UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public String Title { get; set; }
    public virtual List<PhoneNumber> Number { get; set; }
}

public class PhoneNumber
{
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public String Num { get; set; }
    public virtual Int32 PhoneBookId { get; set; }
    public virtual PhoneBook PhoneBook { get; set; }
}
```

Now I can query perfectly fine. The problem is the circular referencing.

Let's say I would want to select every Phonebook thats for the user with the id = 1
My query would be 
`context.phonebook.Where(x=>x.UserId == 1)`
This would load the user and every phonenumber as well.
I could turn off the proxying and I would get nothing but the Phonebook ( no numbers, no user ).

What if I wanted to get every phonenumber too but not the user?
Also I'd have to make sure that getting the phonenumber objects doesnt also mean it's getting the phonebook related to the number too.
I kind of need the proxying to only go one way. Down the ladder and not upwards.

Comment: Three ways to load related data : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your foreign key ids do not need to be `virtual`. You use `virtual` for navigation properties (or other entity type properties) only: your foreign key is not a navigation property, it's just an integer.

Now your question is not related to proxies really, it's related to lazy loading (proxies enable lazy loading by default, which is why you are concerned to them, but that's not necessary).

If you only want to load the specified entities, disable lazy loading and do eager loading:

```
context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

// Load phonebook entries and users matching your id
var result = content.phonebook
                .Include(x => x.Number)
                .Include(x => x.User)
                .Where(x => x.UserId == 1); 

// Load only phonebook entries without users    
var result2 = content.phonebook
                .Include(x => x.Number)
                .Where(x => x.UserId == 1);
```

That simple

*PS: proxies have more advantages to them than lazy loading (like change tracking, etc.). If your problem is lazy loading, turn lazy loading off, not proxies.*

Comment: @MarianneMarkwardt no, you are not. The foreign keys are just integers. Navigation properties point to other entities. They get filled automatically with the foreign entity id, but that's not a "navigation property". To load the other level, you can either use the string syntax (`.Include("Number.OtherLevel")`, or the lambda one: for a navigation property: `Include(s => s.Number.OtherProperty)`, or for a collection: `Include(s => s.Number.Select(t => t.CollectionItem))`. It's all explained here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx (look for *"Eagerly Loading Multiple Levels"*)

Comment: Alright. Thank you very much Jcl. I marked your answer. Although the question may belong to another topic but could you tell me why 

context.phonebooks.Where(x=>x.id == 1)

works but

context.phonebooks.Include(x=>x.title) fails due to the error
"A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType .. does not declare a navigation property with the name 'Title'."

Comment: "Include" works for loading related entities. "Title" is a property of type string, not a related entity (navigation property or collection)

Comment: Yeah.. I just realized right when I hit enter.. Thanks again Jcl. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

In this case it's not proxy creation that's causing misery, it's lazy loading. **Disable it** by all means, and include the navigation properties you want or project your results specifically:

```
context.phonebook
  .Include(x=> x.Number)
  .Where(x=>x.UserId == 1);
// or
context.phonebook
  .Where(x=>x.UserId == 1)
  .Select(x=> new{ 
       Phonebook = x,
       Number = x.Number
       });
```